# How can I upload multiple files to a SQL database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database that I want to upload files to in a column called 'upload'. My code successfully uploads files to the destination folder on the web server but it won't store more than one in the database. When I look at the record on phpMyAdmin the upload column only contains one file path not all of them if there are more than two.

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {

    $total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

        if ($tmpFilePath != "") {
            $newFilePath = "uploads/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

                $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $config_tbl_prefix . " subcontractor_qs (nameofcompany, mainaddress, upload) VALUES ('$_POST[nameofcompany]','$_POST[mainaddress]','$newFilePath')";

                mysql_query($sql);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put files contents to database. Also your code is open for SQL Injection, plus don't use deprecated `mysql_*`.

Comment: Either store file name in separate table in multiple rows or store in one rows with comma separated.

Comment: The mysql_* functions have been removed in PHP7. Use MySQLi instead Or PDO!

Comment: This guy is not putting the file content into the database. Look at the code! @Ross H: Please check the return value of move_upload_file. Maybe it is failing. You could also make an `echo` within the last if-statement, to check if it is reached.

Comment: @MichaelWalter thank you for your answer, the echo reports that both files are being uploaded and they are both in the upload folder but only one path ends up in the database. Any further ideas?

Comment: Debug your code. What is the return value of `mysql_query`? `var_dump()` its value, echo the SQL statements and try to send them via a MySQL Client (like phpmyadmin). Maybe the result of your generated query is not a valid statement.YOu can also run `echo mysql_error ()` after your `mysqL_query()` to see any mysql errors. maybe you have to apply `mysql_real_escape_string()` first on your strings. But, as others already suggested, you should switch to mysqli in general.